vue3-onsenui にて v-ons-tabbar の v-slot + v-ons-tab を利用した場合を利用方法について
Vue3のOnsenUIを利用しています。
タブバーの長押しを解決するため、公式に記載してある、「v-slotとv-ons-tabを利用した」場合のタブバーの実装を検討していますが、うまく動作させることができていません。
リファレンスに記載されている以下を試しています。
参照:
https://ja.onsen.io/v2/api/vue3/v-ons-tabbar.html
Tabbar.vue
<v-ons-tabbar>
  <template v-slot:pages>
    <home-page></home-page>
    <news-page></news-page>
    <settings-page></settings-page>
  </template>

  <v-ons-tab v-for="(tab, i) in tabs"
    :icon="tabs[i].icon"
    :label="tabs[i].label"
    :badge="tabs[i].badge"
    ></v-ons-tab>
</v-ons-tabbar>

上記に必要な各ページコンポーネント（ons-page）は別ファイルとして以下に記載しています。
Home.vue
News.vue
Settings.vue
例えば、Home.vue内は以下のように記載してます。
<template>
  <v-ons-page>
    home
  </v-ons-page>
</template>

利用している各種バージョンは以下です。
vue.js: 3.3.4
vue-onsenui:3.0.0
色々他のサンプルがないか確認したのですが、なかなかv-slotとv-ons-tabを利用した場合の記載を見つけることができず、難儀しています。
なにか、公式記載されている上記のコード以外に必要な記述が必要ならご教示いただけないでしょうか？
もしくはv-slotとv-ons-tabを利用した場合の動作が確認できるサンプルコードを頂戴できないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。
追記
v-ons-tabbar の tabs Propを利用した以下の場合では動作を確認できています。
<v-ons-tabbar
  :tabs="[
    { label: 't1', page: p1 },
    { label: 't2', page: p2, props: { aPageProp: 'hello' } }
  ]"
>
</v-ons-tabbar>


自己解決しました。
原因は、Tabbar.vueにて、componentsプロパティの定義がされていなかったことでした。
